# How to set default range of date picker in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material, datepicker

How can I set default value for date picker. Actually I have two date pickers I value of one date picker add then I have to add same value in second date picker using observable.

```js
export class DatePickerComponent implements OnInit {
dateRange:any;
  range = new FormGroup({
    start: new FormControl(),
    end: new FormControl(),
  });

startTime:any;
endTime:any;
  private unsubscribe: Subject<void> = new Subject();

  constructor( public logsService:LogsService, public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<DatePickerComponent>, @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.logsService.logsTime$.pipe(takeUntil(this.unsubscribe)).subscribe((res)=>{
      this.dateRange=res;
      this.startTime=res.fromDate; // I have to pass this value in form group start as a default value 
      this.endTime=res.toDate;     // I have to pass this value in form group end as a default value 
      console.log("response in date picker one",this.startTime,this.endTime);
    })
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way :

```
 this.startTime=new Date(res.fromDate); 
 this.endTime=new Date(res.toDate);
```

Comment: thanks for your commment . our requirement is to pass values in formControl  start and end